# Vim block select mode - discontinuous lines?

Tags: vim, vi

In Vim, is it possible to do "advanced" block manipulations such as a grid that "skips lines"?

Example:

```
# SCENARIO "A"
This is line   ONE
This is line   TWO
This is line        THREE

# SCENARIO "B"
This is line  ONE
This is line         TWO
This is line  THREE
```

In "Scenario A" above, I can use a single operation with block select to add spaces and put ONE and TWO in nice alignment with THREE.

In "Scenario B," I want to know if a single "block visual" operation can be used to add spaces before ONE and THREE to line them up with TWO.

Comment: What about a macro?

Comment: Afaik, it is not possible to align Scenario B with a single visual block operation. However, as Gonzalo suggested you can use a macro. For example copy `$b20i ^[22|dwj` into register `a`. Then put cursor on first line and type `3@a`.

Comment: or you could use a normal command `%norm $bd$22|p`

Comment: Have you looked into aligning plugins? I use easy-align myself and I absolutely love it

Answer (score 1):

The is no straightforward way to do that visual blocks. I would personally prefer to move the farther away item closer to the other ones and then realign the three at the same time.

Another alternative would be to copy the desired amount of spaces and then insert them in visual block mode (`Ctrl-R + "`) to realign them.

I've made [a short video](https://asciinema.org/a/EOb8SmmI5PIkhFOXNCXQBYNPX) demonstrating what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](https://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)

One of these (once one has learned how to use them) will fix alignment issues far more comfortably than built-in commands can do.